# How do I match the string value only in tree-sitter?

Tags: treesitter

Given that I have the code below in JavaScript/Typescript:

```js
findOne('testing', () => {
});

findLegacy('testing2', () => {
});

findOne('testing3', () => {
});
```

I want to match the string value only using a tree-sitter query.

Here's where I got to, it matches *the whole string, including the quotes*

```scm
(call_expression
  arguments: (arguments ((string)+ @desc))
)
```

Can I match `testing` and not `'testing'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just not possible in tree-sitter